# how to get fonts style from nspopupbutton

Tags: macos, cocoa

I set the list of fontfamilies to a `NSPopupButton`. I don't know How to set the selected font preview to the `NSTextView` 
have tried like this

```
NSString *fontstyle = [popup_button titleOfSelectedItem];
NSFont *fontst =  [NSFontManager:nil willIncludeFont:fontstyle];
[text_view setFont:fontstyle];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I got it...

```
NSString *fontstyle = [popup_button titleOfSelectedItem];
NSString *fontsize = [pop_size titleOfSelectedItem];
CGFloat fntsize = [fontsize floatValue];
NSFont *regular = [NSFont fontWithName:fontstyle size:fntsize];
[text_view setFont:regular];
```

Comment: You need to accept as a correct answer. Then others can see it as a correct solution.